# Exclude json config files in webpack

Tags: json, node.js, webpack, electron

I am working on an Electron app that have a few config files that I do require on in the app. The problem is that when webpack my app all the config files are bundled into the bundle.js file but I would like the files to still be accessible to the user without hacking in the bundle.js file. Is there a way to exclude these files in webpack but still do a require on them?

Comment: Did you ever got to solve that?

Comment: Yes, I used global.require("");